# Failed to load Main-Class manifest attribute from a jar on windows

Tags: java, windows

I'm executing a jar in linux and it works fine here's the command :

```
 java -Djava.ext.dirs=/home/amira/workspace/srd/remap/libs fr.srd.remap.compiler.main.Main ~/Desktop/TDP/VQHFACCOI/VQHFACCOI.xml ~/Desktop/TDP/VQHFACCOI
```

So for a technical issues i need to run it on windows machine so here's the used command :

```
C:\Documents and Settings\walinbj\Desktop\remap-to-win>java -jar remap.jar -Djava.ext.dirs=Facture\libs fr.srd.remap.compiler.Main  C:\Documents and Settings\walinbj\Desktop\remap-to-win\Facture\TDPFAC010.xml
```

i'm getting this error `Failed to load Main-Class manifest attribute from
remap.jar`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From the [javadocs](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/deployment/jar/appman.html):

**Setting an Application's Entry Point**

> If you have an application bundled in a JAR file, you need some way to
> indicate which class within the JAR file is your application's entry
> point. You provide this information with the Main-Class header in the
> manifest, which has the general form:
>
> Main-Class: classname The value classname is the name of the class
> that is your application's entry point.
>
> Recall that the entry point is a class having a method with signature
> public static void main(String[] args).
>
> After you have set the Main-Class header in the manifest, you then run
> the JAR file using the following form of the java command:
>
> java -jar JAR-name The main method of the class specified in the
> Main-Class header is executed.

You basically need to have a manifest file in your jar and in that you need to define your Main-Class attribute:

Manifest-Version: 1.0
Created-By: 1.7.0_06 (Oracle Corporation)
Main-Class: fr.srd.remap.compiler.main.Main

When you run the JAR file with the following command, the main method of Main executes:

java -jar MyJar.jar

Answer (score 2):

Your jar file remap.jar doesn't contain a MANIFEST file with provided main class option. Your need to specify main class as an argument (You did it for linux command line) and provide classpath to the jar. You can't use -jar option for that. Try to change to use following command:

```
C:\Documents and Settings\walinbj\Desktop\remap-to-win>java -classpath remap.jar -Djava.ext.dirs=Facture\libs fr.srd.remap.compiler.Main  C:\Documents and Settings\walinbj\Desktop\remap-to-win\Facture\TDPFAC010.xml
```